# How to make a floating windowless widget in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, desktop-application, gtk3

I'm curious,how can one create a widget similar to [synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project)

Or the likes of [albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/)
.These apps just float on the desktop with 'no window'.My question is,can this be achieved with python using maybe kivy or Gtk or somesuch.Do forgive me if this is the wrong place to be posting this.

Comment: You can do in Python anything you want if you know how. Windowless widgets however is not something that is done. Mentioned apps create a transparent window, so it is there, but you do not see it. And it is defined as on top of everything and so on... If you insist on a completely windowless app, then you have to draw directly on the desktop and on top of other applications and monitor system-wide events to detect when content of your app is interacted with. So, you see, you can do it, but it is not practical.

Comment: Albert looks to be written using Qt. Python has a binding to Qt called PyQt, so you may be able to fully recreate it using PyQt.

Comment: @101 : Yep, both PyQT and wxPython can do it, no problem. I do not know whether TK supports transparent windows or not, but it is possible to create them by reaching directly to the system APIs. If you are feeling crazy you do not need any dependencies at all. You can even use sys APIs only to tweak existing GUIs created by some library like TK, or wx if they do not support some capability or other that the OS provides.

Comment: @Dalen makes sense,I hadn't thought of the transparency thing at all.Good observation.

Comment: @101,I haven't used pyqt in a while now..I prefer gtk or kivy hence my question

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like the following example (the orange GUI is a kivy window):

[image]

this can be achieved by the pywin32 extensions.
Give your kivy app a name:

```
class myApp(App):
    '''Main kivy application class.'''
    title = 'myfloatingapp'
```

Then grab the kivy window (assuming it has focus and is on the foreground), make it a Topmost window (=always on top) and position it on x,y on your desktop . For example:

```
import win32gui
import win32con

mykivywinHndl = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
mykivywinName = win32gui.GetWindowText(mykivywinHndl)
if mykivywinName  == 'myfloatingapp':
    win32gui.SetWindowPos(mykivywinHndl, win32con.HWND_TOPMOST, x_pos, y_pos, width, height, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
```

Comment: Well, the essence of your question is if it is possible to create a floating app window with Kivy. The answer is yes. You just should find the similar lower level OS calls to position the kivy window. I do not know the Ubuntu related ones. Probably that is another question.